# Why would acorn meal still be bitter after cold leaching for a month in the fridge?

Tags: foraging

I've successfully leached, ground and dried acorns to make flour in the past. Problem: currently have a batch of ground acorn meal which I have been cold leaching in the fridge for at least a month. The meal still has bitterness. Don't know if I should persevere, or abandon this batch? Why would leaching take this long? Thanks for reading and any advice!

Comment: Was it from the same tree(s) as before?  How often did you change the water? Comments under the accepted answer to [my own related question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/110725/20413) suggest it can be hard to shift the bitterness.  I cold leached them split at room temperature in plenty of water, changed several times for a few days, then ground mine.  So I suspect you've got a greater ratio of bitter compounds to water (either more acorns or more bitter), and need more changes/rinses

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes, same trees. Changed at least daily, sometimes twice daily. But there's more meal than water in the storage jars, which is a factor, yes. Not very hard to do, so I'll just keep going and hope it will eventually lose the bitter. Would leaving on the counter help the leaching? Wondering if it could create new issues, such as the meal going bad from being at a lower temp.

Comment: If you're going for a month, the fridge is probably best.  I went for a few days and bigger pieces but reckon the leaching wasn't complete

Comment: When I originally dried the acorns in a low slow oven, the meats turned a little brown. In effect, unintentionally roasted. I didn't realize it but also just found out, roasting (or overenthusiastic drying) causes the tannins to be fixed in the nuts. So actually that may be why the tannins won't leach out...may have to give up the batch. Stuff to learn!! Thanks Chris!

Comment: @Lainie let me suggest posting your own answer, so that folks can refer to this in the future.